# Is it possible to get machine mac address using ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net

I need to know that is it possible to get the MAC address of a local machine using ASP .NET?

Comment: yes it is possible using the [ManagementClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) in System.Management dll of .Net framework

Comment: Depends if you mean the server where the asp.net code is running, or the client machine where the user is viewing the application in their browser. You can get the Mac address of the server, but not the client

Comment: Than what will be the procedure to get the client machine mac address?

Comment: @RatsTyagi can you please expedite more?

Comment: You cannot get the client mac address. The browser does not have access to that kind of information, for security reasons. Why do you want it?

Comment: I need to get the mac address of user to provide the rights to user on specific application to that PC only for security reasons.